# PHP: Write associate array in CSV with predefined columns

Tags: php, csv

I would like to write a lot of lines to a csv file via PHP. The problem is that I would like to define the columns of the CSV before writing, e.g. column1, column2, column3.
My data looks like {column1=>A, column3=>B},{column2=>C,column3=>D}. So my data does not contain all columns of the CSV. Is there any way to do so efficiently? If an array does not contain a specific column the value of this row should be empty.

Adding the missing columns to each array before writing it to the csv might be too time consuming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could write an array whith all the columnsin the right order, and then check if your array contians that column, if not, empty value..?

Comment: Currently I just loop over the data and write every line with fputcsv which is quite efficient because I don't have to modify the data at all. If I have to check every line for every key/column the time will increase a lot.